# fastcgi_pass directory not available on Apache + Nginx, how to find it?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, php, nginx, fcgi

I have a `CentOS`, `Apache` and `Nginx` installation. It uses `php 5` handler as fcgi. This server uses `WHM cpanel` and `easyapache`. `fcgi` apply by using `easyapache`. These installation done by my hosting company. When I'm adding following code to `Nginx vhost` it giving me `No such file or directory` error.

> ```
>     location ~ .php$ {
>             try_files $uri /index.php;
>             include fastcgi_params;
>             fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
> ```

When I'm searching `.sock` file in the server, it don't display `.sock` extension file. How to I find the correct `fastcgi_pass` directory and file in ths VPS?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `php-fpm` daemon is certainly binded to a TCP port and not a Unix socket.

Open your `www.conf` file and check if you have something like this :

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

and/or :

```
netstat -anp | grep -i fpm | grep -i listen
tcp     0      0 127.0.0.1:9000        0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      2640/php-fpm
```

On my CentOS 6.5, file `www.conf` is located here : `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`. It could be a different location on your system. Search for it !

If `php-fpm` is binded to a TCP port, you have 2 options :

---

**Option 1 :**

Keep your `www.conf` unchanged :

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

But modify your `Nginx vhost` like this :

```
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
```

---

**Option 2 :**

Keep your `Nginx vhost` unchanged :

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
```

But modify your `www.conf` like this :

```
;listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
listen = /var/run/php-fpm.sock;
```

Comment: Thank you . When I added `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000`, it gives `invalid host in upstream error`. When I'm running `netstat -anp | grep -i fpm | grep -i listen` command, it doesn't give any response. My VPS I can't find 'www.conf' file. Are you talking about `httpd.conf` file? My VPS company still uses CENTOS 6.4 i686 virtuozzo, not the 6.5. Also I can't find `php-fpm.d` directory in my file system. Do you have any idea about this situation? My php handler (fcig) enabled using EasyApache and it uses Apache suEXEC.

Comment: @chris I am really talking talking about `www.conf`, not `httpd.conf`. Are you sure `php-fpm` is installed on your system ? What gives you `ps -ef | grep -i fpm` ? and `yum list installed | grep -i fpm` ?